# C++ compile error: syntax error : '<cv-qualifer>'

Tags: c++, qt

I originally hired someone to code a dll for me and I was using the compiled dll he gave me, but it has a msgbox popup that I needed to remove.  So I removed that from the code and went to recompile.  His code needed the QtCore library, so I downloaded that and installed it.  But in that library I get a lot of errors, all the errors are syntax error : `<cv-qualifer>`

I googled syntax error : `<cv-qualifer>` but it seems its a pretty common error.

Every line that has that error starts with " asm volatile("

I assume asm is assembly?  Am I missing something I need to compile that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT:
Complete error code: error C2059: syntax error : ''
Here is the source where it occurs once.  Everytime it happens it starts with asm volatile

```
asm volatile("0:\n"
             "ldrex %[result], [%[_q_value]]\n"
             "eors %[result], %[result], %[expectedValue]\n"
             "strexeq %[result], %[newValue], [%[_q_value]]\n"
             "teqeq %[result], #1\n"
             "beq 0b\n"
             : [result] "=&r" (result),
               "+m" (_q_value)
             : [expectedValue] "r" (expectedValue),
               [newValue] "r" (newValue),
               [_q_value] "r" (&_q_value)
             : "cc", "memory");
```

Comment: it will help if you add the errors as well

Comment: UmNyobe, I did.  It is in the title and in the message.  Did you want something else?

Bames53, Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: The part of the sourcecode exhibiting the error as well as a more complete error message might help

Comment: error C2059: syntax error : '<cv-qualifer>' is the complete error message, it happens 15 times.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to overflow, is there a way for me to post a longer message? wont let me post all the code here

Comment: I edited OP to add the requested info.

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8xe60cf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is the relevant error description from Microsoft for your compiler. Can you show us a few lines before the `asm volatile` line?

Comment: Multipleinterfaces, in every situation a few lines before asm volatile is
register int result;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have QT as source for ARM there. Are you building for ARM? Do you need to build QT from source?

Comment: The code I need to compile has this
#include <QtCore\QString>
#include <QtXml\QDomDocument>
So I just included the Qt include folder.

Comment: Well, you can't use the ARM version of it :) That there is ARM assembly language, you're using an Intel, most likely.

Comment: Oooh interesting :) Yup, I double checked and realized I included the wrong include folder!.. switch to the proper one and it works!.. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

cv is standardese shorthand for `const` and/or `volatile`.  I'm guessing the `volatile` keyword is the culprit.

asm volatile is supposed to indicate side effects in the assembler code such that the asm code should not be moved.  It looks like a gcc extension that [Visual Studio does differently.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_ordering)

Try __asm volatile and see what happens.  Nope, still gcc specific.

Check the [MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45yd4tzz.aspx).  They use __asm with co cv qualification.

Comment: When I try __asm or _asm I get a ton of different errors everywhere.  I know that isnt a helpful reply to you but its like 200 errors so not really sure how to give you all the details lol.

Comment: I think the problem could be 1) asm volatile is gcc-specific, 2) __asm (without volatile) is how MS does inline assembly - asm doesn't work apparently; 3) The real kicker - MS __asm usses a different assembly language.  It looks like you're porting something from gcc (possibly linux) to windows.  asm is inherently non-portable.  Is there any way you could find out what these asm block are doing and code them in straight C++?  Then worry about asm later (or not at all)?

Comment: I'm surprised that the Qt library would have this problem.  They hammer out cross-platform issues.  Are you cross-compiling from windows x86 to something else?  Also, you wouldn't/shouldn't have to change Qt library code.  Something bigger is going on.

Comment: Looks like you were correct it was from a different language. I was including the wrong include folder (duh!).   

Thanks for the help!